# Netbios binding in server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, netbios, ms-dos

I am creating a middle ground server as a funnel point for our regular network to talk to our legacy network, which is running Lantastic 8.0/8.1 on MS Dos 6.1.

To do so, I need to install Netbios, but I have two NIC's installed, and I need to bind it to a specific one. Is there an easy way to do that, or do I need to remove one NIC, install Netbios and then install the other NIC?

Comment: NetBIOS over TCP support already exists in Windows Server 2008 and is enabled by default for statically assigned ip addresses. What do you mean you're trying to install it?

Comment: @joeqwerty - Blind leading the blind. Our network guy has never installed lantastic, I've never worked on 2008 (I'm on the dev side, not networking).

Comment: He says the problem now is that Lantasti isn't seeing any NIC, regardless of Netbios.

Comment: OK. Understood.

Comment: The other guy might mean "NetBEUI", which was Microsoft's NetBIOS supporting protocol prior to the addition of NetBIOS over TCP/IP capabilities. It looks like at one time Microsoft did have a DOS-compatible NetBEUI client available but it's not clear if you can still get that. Or maybe NetBEUI can also act as a Lantastic client - I can't seem to verify either way. It does look like there might be a Lantastic client for Server 2008 so you might look into getting that.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - We are ending up building a 2003 server instead. 2008 removed the NT components which is what our Lantastic installation uses. I hadn't known about the 2008 client, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Have a reference on that client?

Comment: I just googled lantastic and netbeui.